# Error parsing lifecycle processing instructions when using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.3 with maven (works well on 1.4.2)

Tags: java, spring, maven, schema, pom.xml

The following pom.xml does not work for 1.4.3.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent, and it says "Error parsing lifecycle processing instructions". But once I change the version to 1.4.2, the issue is automatically resolved. 
So my question is, is the 1.4.3 version incompatible with the pom schema definition?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<artifactId>SpringCloudConfig</artifactId>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: have you read this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943612/error-parsing-lifecycle-processing-instructions

Comment: No issue with 1.4.3.RELEASE, i am able to build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the entire .m2 folder or the specific jar files might help, in case there are corrupted jar files in your maven local repository. I solved the problem by removing the C:\Users\yourUserName\ .m2 folder. And then switch back to Eclipse Mars.(I was using Eclipse Neon when the problem occurs). Eclipse Mars is compatible with both the 1.4.2 and 1.4.3 version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to delete entire repo. This is caused by corruption of some spring related jars. Just delete following folder from local m2 repo and update Maven project

.m2\repository\org\springframework

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.4.3.RELEASE
    
    test
    test
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    test

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```